# Traverse matrix in segments

Tags: matlab

I have a huge waveform matrix:

```
[w,fs] = wavread('file.wav');
length(w)
ans =

  258048
```

I want to go through this matrix in segments (say 50) and get the maximum of these segments to compare it to another value. I tried this:

```
thold = max(w) * .04;
nwindows = 50;
left = 1;
right = length(w)/nwindows;
counter = 0;
for i = 1:nwindows
  temp = w(left:right);
  if (max(temp) > thold)
      counter = counter + 1;
  end
  left = right;
  right = right+right;
end
```

But MATLAB threw tons of warnings and gave me this error:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in wlengthdur (line 17)
  temp = w(left:right);
```

Am I close or way off course?

Comment: try using `for i = 1:50:length(w)`. This will allow you to skip every 50 elements. Then you can find the max of the i'th segment with `max(w(i:min(i+49,length(w))))`. You want to use `min` to prevent exceeding the matrix dimensions for the final segment.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to use reshaped to arrange you vector in to a 2D matrix with number of row `n` and columns equal to `ceil(length(w) / n)` i.e. round up so that it is divisible as matlab matrices must be rectangular. This way you can find the max or whatever you need in one step without looping.

```
w = randn(47, 1);
%this needs to be a column vector, if yours isn't call w = w(:) to ensure that it is

n = 5;

%Pad w so that it's length is divisible by n
padded = [w; nan(n - mod(length(w), n), 1)];

segmented_w = reshape(padded, n, []);

max(segmented_w)
```